# Vectors in R, using the components in two vectors to create a new vector

Tags: r, vector

So I have a vector the represents start times (`trt.start`) and end times (`trt.end`).  Each of the start times represents one treatment (which takes 400 days) and the corresponding position in the vector `trt.end` represents the end.

```
trt.start = c(10000,10090,10180,10270, 10360) 
trt.end = c(trt.start + 400)
```

Is there a way to (with out hard coding it), to create a new vector that will represent the duration of each treatment?  So it will result in:

```
c(10000:10400, 10090:10490, 10180:10580, 10270:10670, 10360:10760)
```

I would like to be able to do this without hard coding because the `trt.start` vector will change values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R`, we can use `Map` to get the sequence of corresponding vectors in a `list` and then `unlist` the `list` to create the single `vector`

```
v1 <- unlist(Map(`:`, trt.start, trt.end))
length(v1)
#[1] 2005
```

If we need as a `string`

```
v1 <- sprintf("%d:%d", trt.start, trt.end)
v1
#[1] "10000:10400" "10090:10490" "10180:10580" "10270:10670" "10360:10760"
```

or with `paste`

```
v1 <- paste0(trt.start, ":", trt.end)
v1  
#[1] "10000:10400" "10090:10490" "10180:10580" "10270:10670" "10360:10760"
```

---

Or a vectorized option is to `rep`licate the 'trt.start' and then add with sequence of values

```
v2 <- rep(trt.start, each = 401) + seq_len(401) -1
all.equal(v2, v1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @jrokh Do you need a string `"10000:10400"` because that is not numeric

Comment: The issue is I need the resulting vector to remain in the format so each treatment is a segment like so: `(10000:10400, 10090:10490, 10180:10580, 10270:10670, 10360:10760)`.   My intention is to then use that vector to indicate in subset sections in a column like so `df$column[c((10000:10400, 10090:10490, 10180:10580, 10270:10670, 10360:10760)].

Comment: @jrokh If it is to subset, why not just use thee `v1` I showed first `v1 <- unlist(Map(`:`, trt.start, trt.end))`  It does exactly what you wanted

Comment: When I used `v1 <- unlist(Map(:, trt.start, trt.end))` , the result seems to be a vector from  `[1:2005]'.  The result of  `v1 <- paste0(trt.start, ":", trt.end)' is exactly what I need, but a string, not numeric.

Comment: @jrokh Not following why you need it in a format when the end result is what you wanted.

Comment: @jrokh Just as an example `df1 <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(20), col2 = runif(10)); v1 <- unlist(Map(":", c(3, 8, 17), c(5, 11, 20))); df1[v1, ]` gives the subset of rows or to extract a column `df1$col1[v1]`

Comment: I'm relatively new, so I'm trying out all your solutions to see what the results are.  Just a note on the big picture, I am using this to create a function.  I have a data frame with the column `import` (with is treatment times) and `times`. I will be using this vector to subset: `import$signal[c((10000:10400, 10090:10490, 10180:10580, 10270:10670......)] ` and the length of each of the segments to subset time: `signal$time[c(0:400, 0:400, etc)]`.

Comment: @jrokh For that you need exactly the first solutoion because you are anyway concatenating (`c`) each of the sequence, which is what the `unlist` does from a `list` of vectors to a single vector

Comment: @jrokh Let's say if you store as a string `v1 <- paste0(c(3, 8, 17), ":", c(5, 11, 20))` then to subset the above example 'df1', you may have to either split get the sequence or use `eval(parse` which is not a good optiono at all `unlist(sapply(v1, function(x) eval(parse(text = x))), use.names = FALSE)`